# Can I change the code in designer.vb to use With/End With?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

Today I wanted to add an option to 100 or so columns in several DataGridView collections. I figured I could manually edit the Form's Designer.vb file to copy and paste the option in, but I quickly realized that this would not be an easy task since the option contained the name of the column, so it wasn't something I could just paste in.

I opted to change the code to use With/End With, but after doing so, I got a boatload of errors in the Designer that said "The variable 'VB$t_ref$L0' is either undeclared or was never assigned (that is, from L0 to L99). I did some research and learned that this variable isn't something I'll find in my VB code, but is actually the compiled version of it.

Here's the Before code:

```
Me.DataMatchesHomePlayerID.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
Me.DataMatchesHomePlayerID.HeaderText = "Home Player ID"
Me.DataMatchesHomePlayerID.Name = "DataMatchesHomePlayerID"
Me.DataMatchesHomePlayerID.Width = 144
```

Here's the After code:

```
With Me.DataMatchesHomePlayerID
    .AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
    .HeaderText = "Home Player ID"
    .Name = "DataMatchesHomePlayerID"
    .Width = 144
End With
```

What I don't understand is why this didn't work. Shouldn't I be able to use With/End With in Designer.vb? If it helps, the line I added was the first one (.AutoSizeMode).

Let me know if you need additional information to help me resolve this. I really just need to know if it's okay to finish converting all the code in Designer.vb to use With/End With.

Thanks!

Comment: Take note of the comment near the top of the file, in part `...Do not modify it using the code editor.`  no matter what you do, the IDE will rewrite the file when you make changes

Comment: @Plutonix On point. The Designers code has it's own syntax for writing your programming code. It is creating and reading its content like you would write and read a configuration file for your application. You can edit the designer.vb, but you have to use the same syntax as the designer.

Comment: In addition: There are cases where you have to edit the designer.vb due to bugs in Visual Studio. For example: If you use an image in a Picturebox that you are storing in your ressources folder and then remove the Image for the ressources your designer won't be able to load due to it not removing the image. It will completly crash your form. Only way out: Go to designer file and change the Picturebox.Image to Nothing instead of the reference to the Ressources Image. (Happened to me in VS 2013 Ultimate)

Comment: Thanks for helping out, Plutonix and Luke. I want to mark this as answered (I just put all the code back), but I don't see any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I heeded Plutonix' advice and removed the With/End With's from the Designer.vb file.

Kudos also to Luke who provided some interesting insights as to why this is the case!